# Manually set redux-form field and/or form errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I'm aware that if you throw a `SubmissionError` from your `handleSubmit()` function, the `redux-form` code will fill in the errors of the appropriate fields and/or the form itself.

Yet that API of setting field/form errors, tightly couples our implementation of `handleSumbit()` to be a caller of the `redux-form` code (which contains the `SubmissionError` exception handler).

My use case is to have something like so:

```
function asyncActionDispatcher(values) {                                     
  return (dispatch, getState) => {                                           
    // I'm using getState, which is not accessible in handleSubmit()         
    // But I'd also like to be able to set errors on the form fields and/or the
    // form.                                                                 
  };                                                                         
}                                                                            

function handleSubmit(values, dispatch) {                                    
  dispatch(                                                                  
    asyncActionDispatcher(values)                                            
  );                                                                         
}
```

I can't throw a `SubmissionError` in `asyncActionDispatcher()` because it's called by `redux` and not `redux-form`.

Does `redux-form` have another API to set errors on fields/form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does.

You can use `validate` and `asyncValidate` props to set validator functions for the values of your form (synchronous and asynchronous respectively).

`validate` should be a function that either returns an empty object if validations pass or an object detailing validation errors in the form `{ someField: 'some error', otherField: 'other error' }`

`asyncValidate` on the other hand should return a `Promise` that is resolved normally if validations pass or that is rejected with an object detailing validation errors (see above) if validations do not pass.

`handleSubmit` is implemented in such a way that it runs both synchronous and asynchronous validations before calling `onSubmit`, so if you've set up `validate` and `asyncValidate`, those errors should appear in your form/fields automatically without any additional work.

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

You could also just wait until `asyncActionDispatcher` finishes and continue submitting or reject with a `SubmissionError` depending on what the results from it were.

```
function asyncActionDispatcher(values) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (success) {
      return Promise.resolve('success')
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('error')
    }
  }
}

function onSubmit(values, dispatch) {
  // dispatch whatever action you need to dispatch
  return dispatch(asyncActionDispatcher(values))
    .then(() => {
      // i guess you need to do your actual submitting here
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return new SubmissionError({ _error: 'whatever you want here' })
    })
}

// and in the component
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) }> ... </form>
```

Sources: [Redux-Form docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/), [wrapped component props documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/), [synchronous validation example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncValidation/), [asynchronous validation example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/asyncValidation/)

Comment: `validate` and `asyncValidate` still seem to require the same caller/callee coupling as I mentioned and neither provide you with `getState()`, in order to always get the latest state values.

Comment: I updated the answer to maybe answer to your particular need. If that isn't it, you'll need to edit your question to be clearer about what it is that you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Your updated answer does indeed solve the problem of granting access to `getState()` and being able to set form/field errors. Both our answers are now slightly different means to the same end, but I'll give the answer to you, because yours makes use of the `dispatch()` return value nicely.

Comment: Actually before I grant you the answer, I'd like to edit yours, to cut out the original answer pertaining to `validate` and `asyncValidate`, because I was never interested in client-side validation. I just wanted to get access to `getState()` while still being able to set errors on the form/fields.

Answer (score 11):

> Does redux-form have another API to set errors on fields/form?

Another option here when `asyncValidate` and other options proposed won't work (for example because validations consider multiple forms) is to dispatch `updateSyncErrors` directly. Example usage below:

```
const { updateSyncErrors } = require('redux-form/lib/actions').default;

dispatch(updateSyncErrors('formName', {
  fieldName: 'Some Error Message'
}));
```

Comment: ur a life saver

Comment: Calls it twice for me.  First time with the error message, then second time it clears it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleSubmit()` is called like so:

```
handleSubmit(values, dispatch, props)
```

...where one of the properties of that `props` Object is a `stopSubmit()` function.

That's what you want to use, where it's API is similar to as described [here](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/):

```
stopSubmit(form:String, errors:Object)
// Flips the submitting flag false and populates submitError for each field.
```

You would need to specify the unique `form` string identifier when importing that function yourself and using it, but if you use the version past to your `handleSubmit()` (via the `props` Object), then you don't need to provide the argument for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm throwing `SubmissionError` from the `.catch()` callback of axios, which is called from inside a thunk, so I think you should be able to do the same from within ReduxSaga. Just make sure to `return` so that you don't get an uncaught exception error. In my case, the thunk returns the axios call, and inside of `.handleSubmit()` I return the thunk.

Answer (score 0):

the `onSubmit` callback has `values`, `dispatch`, `props` arguments. you can also use the `updateSyncErrors` method

```js
props.updateSyncErrors({form_field_name: "Some field level error"})
```